# is it still advisible to use eclipse/intellij for grails development?

Tags: java, eclipse, grails, groovy

one thing I hate about java development are their IDE's, and configuration/setup involved to initially get going.

does grails have these issues? from the looks of it, it seems you need a command line open and then any text editor will do. (apart from a mysql and tomcat install).

are these assumptions correct or its better to get eclipse setup also?

Comment: Sort of a side question but all Java IDE:s have worked well for me out of the box, what exactly are you configuring?

Comment: tomcat, jdk, libraries.  i just find eclipse to be counter intuitive,and intellij looks ugly on a mac.

Comment: but I really like the direction grails is going, and it is exciting using spring but in a more rapid dev way.

Comment: Intellij IDEA rocks on OSX, and it has built in Grails support at the project level. To be productive in Java an IDE is required.

Comment: then try NetBeans, you can get it with Java EE server (Glassfish) out of the box. NetBeans has very good support for alternative JVM languages such as Groovy, JRuby etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend NetBeans over Eclipse for Groovy/Grails development.  I like Eclipse for Java, but for Groovy/Grails the support in NetBeans is vastly superior.  I can't speak to IntelliJ directly, but I have heard good things.

You are correct in stating that an IDE is not strictly necessary, and its advantages are less in Groovy compared to Java.  For instance, code complete is a much less exact science with dynamic languages.  Still though, I do find it convenient to have the project structure more easily navigable and syntax highlighting is good for catching pesky missing quotes and other things the IDE can identify.

Comment: I would recomment the opposite. The eclipse Groovy plugin *used* to be horrible, but since the release of the SpringSource Tool Suite 2.3, it's quite good. I used Netbeans inbeteween and was not impressed.

Comment: Yeah, I have to agree with you in terms of NetBeans as a general IDE.  I find that NetBeans is often getting in my way, but for Groovy/Grails support I have been willing to live with it.  I'm going to check out the SpringSource Tool Suite on your recommendation.  After a brief review of the description on their website, it does seem to be a huge improvement over the plugins that were available just a few months ago (maybe a little longer, I don't remember exactly when I last looked).

Comment: After trying out STS for a short time, I am going back to NetBeans.  I stand by my original statement: Groovy/Grails support in NetBeans is vastly superior to Eclipse, even STS.  The integration with the grails commands is clunky at best.  Syntax highlighting in GSPs is a little bit better in STS in my opinion.  I would say for groovy files it is a draw.  But when it comes to running, debugging, or creating new stuff, STS feels extremely awkward and impeding compared to NetBeans. You have to accept other shortcomings in NetBeans, but for now it's advantage NetBeans, at least for Groovy/Grails.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a matter of personal preference. The arguments for and against using an IDE when doing Grails development are more or less the same as for any other language though the case for an IDE is weaker when using a dynamically-typed language like Groovy.

A lot of Groovy/Grails developers seems to use a text editor (TextMate on the Mac is particularly popular), but personally, I use IntelliJ.

Comment: actually, since you still hook into Java libraries, and IDE is useful BUT do you build your java libraries in a seperate project and import it or?

Answer (score 1):

Since about 4 months I'm working with the SpringSource Tool Suite; for me (personal preference!) this is the most intuitive and balanced IDE to work with.

Before, I used IntelliJ, Eclipse and NetBeans, in this order, and every IDE had something disturbing. IntelliJ was fast and comfortable to work with but expensive and the community verion doesn't feature Grails integration; Eclipse has/ had an awful Groovy/ Grails plugin and crashed all the time; Netbeans was terribly slow and the interface is not that intuitive (for me).

STS impressed me with 'just working'. I haven't discovered any killer features yet, or it isn't incredibly fast, but I like to work with it.

On the other side, I've also developed smaller apps just with a console and a text editor (with java source code highlighting :-) ... but only non-productive ones.

Comment: Yeah, the spring source version of the groovy/grails plugin is much better than it used to be. The amount of work to configure the plugin is really not much more than it would be to work from the command line with a text editor.

Answer (score 1):

Our team has tried the three big-dogs (NetBeans, IntelliJ, and Spring STS).  As noted above, all have pros and cons, but we ended up settling on NetBeans as the most well rounded for our needs (which includes Maven).  You should try them all and see what you think.  The good news is that the projects are self defining, so you should be able to swap between IDE's with minimal pain.